# jplayer how to show a loadding img after hitting play while the video is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jplayer

everyone,

I'v made a video player use jplayer, I have no idea how to show a loadding img after user hitting play button while the video is not loaded, it means show a loadding gif image while loadding the media file.

will be very appreciate if you knows this.